# Как убедиться, что object возможно преобразовать к числовому типу (C#)?

Tags: c#, типы-данных

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number) увидел такой пример:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(object Expression)
{
    double retNum;

    bool isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum );
    return isNum;
}
```

Но используя его я часто получаю такую ошибку:

> column "nan" does not exist

Т.е. `NaN` он считает числом.

И по поводу десятичного разделителя: это, насколько я понимаю, зависит от настроек локали, и где-то это точка, а где-то - запятая?

Каким гарантированным способом можно проверить, число это, или нет?

Comment: GetType() не подходит?

Comment: я получаю данные как строку

Comment: Подправил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nan он считает за число

а это плохо? Можно добавить банальную проверку

```
public static bool IsNumeric(object Expression)
{
    double retNum;

    bool isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum );
    if (isNum)
    {
       isNum = !(new double[]
         {double.PositiveInfinity, 
          double.NegativeInfinity, 
          double.NaN}).Contains(retNum);
    }   
    return isNum;
}
```

Насчет разделителя не могу ничего умнее предложить чем

```
bool isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression).Replace(',','.'), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum );
```

Comment: с разделителем может случится беда в разных локалях, для этого и используется: `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`

Comment: @Dmitry, а какая беда?

Comment: ну а для какой цели делать замену запятой на точку? если мы и так используем любые возможные разделители?

Comment: @Dmitry, Double.Parse(Convert.ToString("12,7"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) возвращает мне 127

Comment: ну да, скорее надо использовать `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.Inva‌​riantInfo`

Comment: @Dmitry , получаю   base {System.SystemException}: {"Входная строка имела неверный формат."}

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий способ:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(object expression)
{
    if (expression == null)
        return false;

    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(expression.GetType()))
    {
        case TypeCode.Byte:
        case TypeCode.SByte:
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
        case TypeCode.UInt64:
        case TypeCode.Int16:
        case TypeCode.Int32:
        case TypeCode.Int64:
        case TypeCode.Decimal:
        case TypeCode.Double:
        case TypeCode.Single:
        case TypeCode.Char:
            return true;
    }

    string exprStr = Convert.ToString(expression);
    double doubleNum;

    return (Double.TryParse(exprStr, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out doubleNum)
        || Double.TryParse(exprStr, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out doubleNum))
        && !Double.IsNaN(doubleNum) && !Double.IsInfinity(doubleNum);
}
```

Достоинства подхода:

- Корректно воспринимаются числа, заданные строкой, как в текущей, так и в нейтральной локали. Применительно к русской локали это означает, что воспринимаются десятичные разделители как `.` (точка), так и `,` (запятая).
- Корректно обрабатывается значение `null` аргумента.
- Как и указано в тексте вопроса, числа `Double.NaN`, `Double.PositiveInfinity` и `Double.NegativeInfinity` числами не считаются. Для них метод возвращает `false`.

---

*Вообще говоря, если вам требуется подобная проверка, то вполне вероятно, что с архитектурой приложения что-то не в порядке. Обычно требуется проверить не является ли объект экземпляром какого-то конкретного типа. Без приведения к конкретному типу, за редким исключением, в работе с объектом не очень много смысла.*

Comment: Так и думал, что придётся перебирать сопоставляемые локализации вручную.

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this object Expression)
{
    var retType = Expression.GetType();
    if(retType == typeof(string))
    {
        double d = 0;
        return Expression != null && double.TryParse(Expression.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out d);            
    }
    // можно построить конструкцию со всеми числовыми типами
    // так мы гарантировано проверим число ли это.
    var isNum = retType == typeof(int) || retType == typeof(long);
    if(isNum) return isNum;
}
```

**UPD:** в данном варианте используется екстеншен

Comment: У вас ошибка компиляции

Answer (score -3):

```
try {
    object sumUbit;
    float q = float.Parse(sumUbit.toString);
}
catch {
    MessageBox.Show("Не число","внимание");
}
```

а если нет, тогда я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Это не ответ, уже не говоря о синтаксических ошибках и существующей перегрузке TryParse, которая позволяет избежать исключения.

Comment: @Align возможно, это ответ с ошибками или далеко не самое лучшее решение. Но почему совсем не ответ-то?

Comment: @NickVolynkin потому что по сравнению с кодом из вопроса не изменено ничего существенного